# fastcgi-mono-server4 or xsp4 Wait timeout (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)

Tags: asp.net, nginx, mono, xsp4, fastcgi-mono-server

I was able to run web site in mono on my debian server and mostly it runs fine, but every now and then I get System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception with Wait timeout description. I've tested on 5.10 and 6.12 also in both fastcgi + nginx and xsp4. I get same behaviour in both versions and absolutely no logs whatsoever. The same URL works 9 out of 10 times, so there is nothing wrong with the code.

Only thing I get is a error page with error 500 without a stack trace.

[image: Error page]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since the introduction of ASP.NET Core, not much improvement has been there in Mono ASP.NET, so don't waste too much time on that route and migrate to ASP.NET Core please.

Comment: Great.... But that's the problem. Currently I'm bound to this code stack and can't move it to .NET Core yet. I'm looking only to tip to point me to the right direction to make it work correctly, because at the moment this is my only unresolved issue with this site, all the rest is working perfectly fine.